# Check memory in use for all php scripts

Tags: php, memory-management

I'm running few scripts in background by [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

There is an option to check memory used by current running script with **[memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)**.
Is there any way to get/calculate memory allocated by all running php scripts ?

Comment: is [this what you're looking for?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) Oh wait, all PHP processes? I guess you'd have to ask the system you're running PHP on, most of the time scripts run one at the time (on request) not continuous

Comment: @Xyv, yes all scripts. I can check on CLI with 'free -m' but I need it on demand when logging actions inside script from php

Comment: This might sound a little dirty, but is there a chance you can store the output of this function? Add it up for every file you execute untill your request is done, and then unset it?

Comment: Sound interesting. You gave me direction, thanks.